# s3 bucket replication in multiple regions using lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

Usecase: Replicate s3 bucket in multiple regions in the same AWS account

This code is replicating bucket in only one region. I tried to add this line `python print vikash` before `python s3.copy_object` but it iterates only one times.

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import sys
import traceback
import re


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print 'Recieved following event'
    print '--------------------------------------------------'
    print event
    print '--------------------------------------------------'
    try:
        # Obtain destination account Credentials



        bucks = ['bucket1-deploy-ap-northeast-1', 'bucket2-deploy-ap-south-1']

        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        records = event['Records']
        print records
        for record in records:
            src_buck = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
            src_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
            if re.match('^ObjectCreated:*', record['eventName']):
                for des_buck in bucks:
                    print des_buck
                    print "vikash"

                    print s3.copy_object(ACL='bucket-owner-full-control', Bucket=des_buck, Key=src_key,
                                   CopySource={'Bucket': src_buck, 'Key': src_key}, StorageClass='STANDARD')
                    print 'Successfully copied %s to %s' % (src_key, des_buck)


            elif re.match('^ObjectRemoved:*', record['eventName']):
                for des_buck in bucks:
                    s3.delete_object(Bucket=des_buck, Key=src_key)
                    print 'Successfully deleted %s from %s' % (src_key, des_buck)
```

Comment: Are you not better off with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html?

Comment: @Istvan CRR only supports a single target bucket.

Comment: Cannot be chained?